# What happen if I change the category in Play store?

Tags: android

I have published an app in Google Play. I want to change the category of the app. What would happen with the rating and ranking? Just want to clear things up before I do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your *customer reviews* will remain the same, however if you have a certain ranking in one category, than you will be put at the appropriate spot in the other category. If you have 5 stars, you'll still have 5 after changing it.